# Is it possible to integrate Brightcove in iOS app?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, appstore-approval, live-streaming

I want to integrate the Brightcove https://www.brightcove.com/en/ in my iOS app for implementing Video Live Streaming & broad casting.
And also getting data form Brightcove cloud and its API's.

I know it is possible in Android.
If it is possible in iOS then if there is any issues / challenges while uploading the app to the Appstore.

OR
is there any other alternative / best way for doing this please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if there is any issues / challenges while uploading the app to the Appstore -- no issues you can upload to appstore

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Thank you for quick reply. So finally I am integrating into my iOS app right.

Comment: ya you can do .\

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate the [iOS SDK](https://support.brightcove.com/overview-brightcove-player-sdk-ios) provided by the brighcove.
Appstore will not reject the App until and unless it violates the App store guidelines [link](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will follow this https://support.brightcove.com/overview-brightcove-player-sdk-ios